# why would this two mips instructions cause data hazards in pipeline?

Tags: assembly, mips, pipeline

I am learning the pipeline in mips and was told tha this two instruction:

```
jal addr;
store $ra;store the value of $ra into memory
```

would cause data hazards, but I don't understand why.Could anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `store` is, but all normal branch and jump instructions on MIPS are executed together with the immediately following instruction. In most trivial cases you may think that the branch/jump is executed the last and that other instruction, the first.

However, I'd not be surprised if the paired instructions execute internally pretty much as one indivisible instruction instead of two separate ones.

The potential problem here is that `jal` stores in `$ra` the address of the instruction that follows `store`. If `store`, or whatever instruction it is, uses `$ra`, there may be a race condition, data hazard, whatever you call it, between the two accesses to `$ra` and the end result may not be determinate or what one might naïvely expect.

Comment: well it's not real instructions but simplified instructions.store means store the value of $ra into memory.

Comment: What would be the memory location, as there must be one?

Comment: yes there is a memory location, but it seems to be less important here.I think  'store' reads $ra only after the subroutine that 'jal' jumps to has been finished so there should not be hazard. So the question becomes "what instruction would be fetched? 'store' or the instrucion located in where 'jal' jumps to ?"

Comment: There should be no ambiguity in what instruction will be fetched. The ambiguity is in the value of `$ra` used in the two instructions. You may have an ambiguity in the instruction if you replace that `store` (which, I suppose, is just `sw`) with another jump/branch instruction. Other than that the target address of the branch/jump instruction is not going to be ambiguous, unless, you do something like `jr $v0` immediately followed by `li $v0, 1234`.

Comment: `So `jal` stores `PC+4` into `$ra`, if this value is exactly the programmer wants to store into memory by `store`, there would be no hazard. is it right?

Comment: What about the value of `$ra` before `jal`? I don't think there's any guarantee that you'll get one or the other and not something else.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction in a MIPS branch delay slot is always fully executed before the branch is executed. So the `store $ra` instruction will store the value of `$ra` that existed **before** the `jal` instruction updates `$ra`. In other words this sequence:

```
    li  $ra, 0x1234
 L: jal addr
    nop
    store $ra, mem    # mem <- L + 8
```

will store a different value into memory than this sequence will:

```
    li  $ra, 0x1234
    jal addr
    store $ra, mem    # mem <- 0x1234
```

This is not an undefined sequence in the MIPS architecture, so the result is predictable.

The MIPS assembler will normally insert a `nop` after the `jal` unless `noreorder` is set.